# question about SQL query

Tags: sql

Given a relation R with n columns. Use sql to returns the tuples having the maximum number of occurrences of the values. I have no idea how to do query horizontally?

Comment: Homework, I presume?

Comment: This sounds like a programming homework assignment to me...  What is the Stack Overflow policy on cheating ;)?

Comment: @slifty Cheating or not, [here's the policy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on asking and answering homework questions. Please note, @chrislee

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment. If it is, please say so. Also, you're more likely to get better help if you include code examples and ask specific questions. Just give it a shot, show us your work, and tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: We just need to give an advice.. :)

Comment: You may well have no idea how to do horizontal queries, and I, for example, have no idea whether a tuple can have identical values, whether I should search ocurrences of a value within its column or within all `n` columns, and what exactly is meant by a tuple 'having the maximum number of ocurrences of the values'. Should I count each one's ocurrences and then see which tuple has the maximum sum of those for each of its values? If you have answers for any of those, please add them to your posted question rather than as a comment. If it's not too late, that is.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT MAX(t.*) FROM mytable t

or

SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c FROM mytable

or

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM mytable

it depends on which SQL implementation you are referring to, and generally more information about the query. but the above examples should get you started so you can google some terms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by querying horizontally.  Is it one relation with multiple key columns linking the two tables?  Sounds like you might just need to group by those columns and order by count(*) descending...